# How to give a Class to an QBO v3 entity?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

In v2 of QBO we had an ability to pass the Class (e.g. string name of a class) to any of the entities (Customer, Invoice, Payment etc). To be able to sort/group them by the classes. The question is: **how to do the same in v3?**

Tried to send some Class entities to QBO - they are being created, but never assigned to any of entities. If you give, for example, a Class Reference to an Invoice (setClassRef()) - it won't populate the Class field of Invoice in QBO. And what is more interesting - if you give an existing Class (created via Classes menu of QBO - https://qbo.intuit.com/app/class) to an Invoice in QBO (populate Class field) and then fetch this invoice's entity - it WON'T contain any Class reference information. Which is strange.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you having a Essential or Plus subscription? Class tracking can be enabled only for Plus.

Comment: You are right, this feature is only for Plus. We've tested it with Plus account and got the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have enabled Class tracking from Preference Tab

Here is one example where class is being referenced from Invoice.

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-03T09:14:13.444-08:00">
  <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1" totalCount="1">
    <Invoice domain="QBO" sparse="false">
      <Id>1</Id>
      <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
      <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-03-03T09:13:52-08:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-03T09:13:52-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
      </MetaData>
      <DocNumber>1001</DocNumber>
      <TxnDate>2014-03-03</TxnDate>
      <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
      <Line>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <LineNum>1</LineNum>
        <Description>Test product desc</Description>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SalesItemLineDetail>
          <ItemRef name="Hours">2</ItemRef>
          <UnitPrice>0</UnitPrice>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
      </Line>
      <Line>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
        <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SubTotalLineDetail />
      </Line>
      <CustomerRef name="Customer123">2</CustomerRef>
      <BillAddr>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Line1>Customer123</Line1>
        <Lat>32.8856854</Lat>
        <Long>-96.9343488</Long>
      </BillAddr>
      <ClassRef name="CLASS-1">3000000000000199718</ClassRef>
      <SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
      <DueDate>2014-04-02</DueDate>
      <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
      <ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>false</ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>
      <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
      <EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
      <Balance>0</Balance>
      <Deposit>0</Deposit>
      <AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
      <AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
      <AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
      <AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
    </Invoice>
  </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

UI snapshot

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We are good with Invoice now. And what about other entities. Do they have an ability to be applied to some Class? I didn't see any classRef on Customer, nor the Payment.

Comment: Mainly transaction entities(invoice, journal entry) have this feature. For details please refer docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference. API mimics the the behaviour of QBO UI. Receive Payments or BillPayments(which has linked transactions) doesn't have this feature in QBO UI either. Thanks

Comment: I wonder, can I create an entity, in particular Customer, with a certain Id?

Comment: No. Ids are internal object identifier(generated by service). You can't explicitly mention objectId